# How to qurey current OpenGL PBO memory status (total/currently available)?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using OpenGL pixel buffer objects (PBO / `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER`) to upload data asynchronly from CPU memory to GPU memory.

I use the classical approach for fast data upload with PBOs: I create a `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER`, I map it to get an address in CPU memory space, I copy my data to this location. Later on, when the renderer requires the data, I feed the PBO into my OpenGL texture. This works very well and very fast. I'm confident that my implementation is correct, but thats not the point here.

To my understanding, PBO memory is allocated in a dedicated area within the system memory. This area is also called "shared GPU memory" and you can see its status ie. in Windows task manager.

I'm facing the following problem: I'm using a lot PBOs and at one point, the "shared GPU memory" is full, my application crashes and the NVidia driver gives me an out of memory error. I'm not able to catch this error with `glGetError() == GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY`. To my understanding, this error reporting is not reliable. **How can I check the size of the total/currently available PBO memory/shared GPU memory?** I have not found a way with OpenGL so far. Do other GPU APIs (DirectX, Vulkan, CUDA) offer useful functions for that?

Comment: "*I'm not able to catch this error with glGetError() == GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY.*" Even if it did, it wouldn't matter, as OpenGL offers no way to get out of that scenario. Once OpenGL throws OOM, the state of the system is left undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL provides no mechanisms to see how much of any kind of memory is still available or even how much the hardware has. Vulkan allows you to query the latter, but even it doesn't allow you to check availability. Mostly because the answer to available memory questions would be outdated by the time you got it, since that answer may depend on what other *applications* are doing.

To avoid this, simply keep track of your own allocations. The simplest way to do that is to allocate one big PBO, and subdivide it internally as you need it. Essentially, treat the one PBO as a "heap" which you allocate from. That way, if you ever run out of room for suballocations, you'll know because it's *your* code that couldn't suballocate memory from its "heap".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was expeceting something like this, but was hoping for a better solution. Good idea with allocation a huge chunk of PBO memory.